# Just and Weese II exercise 13.20

Tags: set-theory

I'm wondering if the following exercise from Just and Weese's Discovering Modern Set Theory II is correct:

${\bf Exercise 13.20}$ Let $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal. Suppose $\langle P, \leq\rangle$ is a p.o. with the $\kappa$-c.c. and $F$ is a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter in $\langle P, \leq\rangle$. [Then] there exists $p\in F$ with no incompatible elements below  $p$... (p. 7)

A ${\it filter}$ on $\langle P, \leq\rangle$ is a subset of $P$ which is closed upwards and contains lower bounds for any two of its elements. An ${\it ultrafilter}$ is a filter which is not a proper subset of any other filter.

I ask because two exercises leading up to it are, seemingly, incorrect; and the only way I can think of proving Exercise 13.20 is by using them. In particular, Exercise 13.18(a) is:

... if $C$ is a finite predense subset of a p.o. $\langle P, \leq\rangle$ and $F$ is an ultrafilter in $\langle P, \leq\rangle$, then $F\cap C \not = 0$. (p.7)

This seems to fall foul of the following counterexample:

We define the following ordering $<^*$ on $\omega\cup\{\langle n, 0\rangle:n\in\omega\}\cup \{\langle 0, 1\rangle\}$:

$m <^* n$ iff $n< m$

$\langle n, 0\rangle <^* m$, for $m\leq n$

$\langle n, 0\rangle <^* \langle 0, 1\rangle$

Then $\{\langle 0, 1\rangle\}$ is a finte predense subset in the new ordering, but $\omega$ is an ultrafilter.

Comment: Using a $\kappa$-complete atomless filter over $P$, you can build a binary tree of height $\kappa$ where each node is a condition in $P$ with incompatible children. Then you can take a fishbone in this tree consisting of $\kappa$ many pairwise incompatible conditions contradicting the $\kappa$-cc-ness of $P.$

Comment: Ok, good. So $\langle 2n, 0\rangle$ has nothing below it. So if it's compatible with $2n+1$, $\langle 2n, 0\rangle<^* 2n+1$. But it isn't - it's only below $m\leq 2n$. Does that sound right?

Comment: Oops, you're right.  I am going to delete my bogus comments, go drink some coffee, and then look at the question again, hopefully making fewer silly mistakes.

Comment: :) - thanks for looking at it! And sorry again for writing it down wrong!

Comment: Perhaps there is some unstated assumption on the partial ordering, such as separativity?  Otherwise, can't we get an even simpler counterexample just by considering the two-element linear ordering $\{0,1\}$ with the usual ordering? $\{1\}$ is an ultrafilter that is disjoint from the finite pre-dense set $\{0\}$.

Comment: Sorry for being dense, but isn't $\{0, 1\}$ also a filter? It can't be separativity, because that's not been introduced yet. My best guess is that the extra assumption is that $P$ is well-met in their sense -- that is, any elements with a lower bound have a greatest lower bound. But then we don't seem to need to assume that $\kappa$ is regular in the proof of 13.19.

Comment: In general, it looks like if $F$ has a least element, then we can always get a filter by adding some member of a predense set -- just add the element comparable with $F$'s least element plus their lower bound and close upwards.

Comment: Yes, but $P$ itself is always a filter.  The filter $\{1\}$ is maximal among _proper_ filters.  And more generally if try to add any element of your predense set to your filter, it may generate the entire poset (closing upward, and closing under greatest lower bounds if you are assuming those exist.)

Comment: I don't think that's the notion they're working with (see p.3) - sorry that wasn't clear! Also, if P contains incompatible elements, it won't be a filter in their sense.

Comment: I don't have the book.  The filter $\{1\}$ in $\{0,1\}$ with the usual (linear!) ordering doesn't contain incompatible elements.  Is your definition of an ultrafilter different from mine?

Comment: I've updated with Just and Weese's definitions.

Comment: Oh, that differs from my definition of ultrafilter as a filter that is maximal among proper filters (in particular they differ for the silly case of linear orderings.)  By the way, when I wrote "$P$ itself is always a filter" I meant for linear orderings; of course it's false in general.

Comment: Just to be clear, it now seems to me that your counterexample works under those definitions and mine doesn't.  But maybe hot_queen's comment can help with your main question.

Comment: Thanks, Trevor! I need to think more about hot_queen's suggestion.

Comment: @hot_queen: could you spell out your suggestion a little more? In particular, I'm not sure I know what a fishbone is in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for every $p \in F$, there are incompatible conditions in $P$ below $p$. Inductively construct a fishbone $\{(p_i, q_i) : i < \kappa \}$ such that:

(1) For each $i < \kappa$, $p_i \in F$ and $q_i$ is incompatible with $p_i$.

(2) For each $j < i < \kappa$, both $p_i, q_i \leq p_j$.

At stage $i$, pick a condition $p \in F$ below all $p_j$'s, $j < i$. Then take a maximal antichain $A$ (of size at least 2) in $P$ below $p$ and notice that your ultrafilter $F$ contains exactly one of these conditions (since $F$ is $\kappa$-complete, $p \in F$ and $|A| < \kappa$) say $q$. Put $p_i = q$ and let $q_i$ be any other member of this antichain.

But now $\{q_i : i < \kappa\}$ is an antichain in $P$ which is impossible.

Addendum 1: List $A = \{a_i : i < \lambda\}$, where $\lambda < \kappa$. Suppose $F$ is disjoint with $A$. Then by maximality of $F$, for each $i < \lambda$, there is some $b_i \in F$ such that $a_i$ is incompatible with $b_i$. Using $\kappa$-completeness of $F$, pick some $b \in F$ below all $b_i$'s and also below $p$. But then, $A \cup \{b\}$ is a larger antichain in $P$ below $p$.

Addendum 2: Suppose $F$ is a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter over a $\kappa$-cc separative poset $P$ and $p \in P$ is compatible with every member of $F$. Then $p \in F$.

Proof: Suppose first that there is some $q \leq p$ such that every extension of $q$ is compatible with every member of $F$. Then every member of $F$ is above $q$ as $P$ is separative. Hence the principal filter above $q$ is proper extension of $F$ which is impossible. To obtain such a $q$, consider a maximal antichain $A$ of conditions below $p$ which are incompatible with some member of $F$. Using $\kappa$-cc-ness of $P$ and $\kappa$-completeness of $F$, we can assume that there is some $r \in F$ which is incompatible with every member of $A$. Let $q$ be a condition extending both $r$ and $p$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you just say why exactly F will have to contain an element of A? Sorry for being slow!

Comment: No problem. I added a little more explanation.

Comment: So, I had a proof which would have worked if whenever $p$ is compatible with everything in $F$, then $p\in F$. It almost looks like you're using that in the second line - ``Then by maximality...". Why is that true here? (I think it's that move I'm getting stuck on).

Comment: If $p$ is compatible with everything in $F$, then you can add $p$ to $F$ and take the generated filter which is at least as big as $F$.

Comment: Generated as in: add lower bounds and then close upwards?

Comment: Just to be clear: the worry is that since we don't have greatest lower bounds, merely adding lower bounds won't give us a filter base. And it wasn't clear to me how to show that one exists for $p$ added to $F$. (Thanks again for all the help!)

Comment: I understand - Give me a little more time.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum! That seems right to me, and also sheds light on the subsidiary question about exercise 13.18(a) (though I think that my counterexample can be modified to also be separative - though it won't satisfy the c.c.c.). But the assumption that $P$ is separative needs to be added, right?

Comment: I don't know if you need that $P$ is separative. Do you have a counterexample to the theorem without that assumption?

Comment: Nope. I couldn't come up with one; hence the question. It would be great to know if it's necessary! BTW the proof I had was: if every element of $F$ has incompatible elements below it, its compliment is dense. So there's a maximal anti-chain A disjoint from $F$ of size less than $\kappa$. It's simple to show that some element of A is compatible with everything in $F$. Then we could use your addendum 2.

Comment: Your argument is more straightforward. Let me know if you can drop the separativity assumption.